# A matrix polynomial converging to $A^T$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

> Does there exist a sequence of matrices $A_i$ such that $$\sum^\infty_{i=0}A_iA^i=A^T$$

i tried inputing $A= 0, I$ but these don't give any substantial information except $$\sum^\infty_{i=0}A_i=I$$
if we take the classical example of a nilpotent matrix $\left[\begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \\ \end{matrix}\right]$
$$A_1 \left[\begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \\ \end{matrix}\right] = \left[\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \\ \end{matrix}\right]$$
I don't know how to progress from here, any help?

Comment: Do you mean that "A certain matrix $A$ being given, does there exist a sequence $A_i$ such that ..." ?

Comment: @JeanMarie, No, I’m talking about a general sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is impossible in the last case of $A$ you consider. Just multiply both sides by $A$ on the right. The LHS becomes 0,
and the RHS becomes non-zero.